Why the exit print more strlines in my screen?
I try to make a variation of "cut -c5- " with c using pipes and forks. When i run the program and giving a small .txt file to see if it runs, the program prints me more lines than the file lines.
Here is the code in C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

void function1(char *argv[]) {    //

        pid_t pid1, pid2;
        int pipefd1[2], pipefd2[2];
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        ssize_t byteRead;

        if (pipe(pipefd1) == -1) {    // Create pipe1
            perror("pipe1");
            return;
        }

        if (pipe(pipefd2) == -1) {    // Create pipe2
            perror("pipe2");
            return;
        }

        pid1 = fork();    // Create fork1
        if (pid1 == -1) {
            perror("fork1");
            return;
        }

        pid2 = fork();    // Create fork2
        if (pid2 == -1) {
            perror("fork2");
            return;
        }

        if (pid1 == 0) {    // Child
            close(pipefd1[1]);
            dup2(pipefd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipefd1[0]); 

            close(pipefd2[0]);
            dup2(pipefd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pipefd2[1]); 

            execlp("cut", "cut", "-c5-", NULL);
            perror("exec");
            return;
        }
        else {    // Parrent
            close(pipefd1[0]);    // Close reading

            int filefd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

            if (filefd == -1) {
                perror("Error opening file!");
                close(pipefd1[1]);
                return;
            } 

            memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);    // Clear the buffer before using it

            while ((byteRead = read(filefd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {    // Writting the infile to pipefd[1]
                write(pipefd1[1], buffer, byteRead);
            } 

            close(filefd); 
            close(pipefd1[1]);

            wait(NULL);

        }

        if (pid2 == 0) {    // Child
            close(pipefd2[1]);

            while ((byteRead = read(pipefd2[0], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {

                char *token = strtok(buffer, "\n");
                while (token != NULL) {
                    printf("«Data received through pipe: %s\n", token);
                    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
                }
            } 

            close(pipefd2[0]);
            return;
        }     
        else {    // Parent
            close(pipefd2[0]);    // Close reading
            close(pipefd2[1]);    // Close writting    

            wait(NULL);
        } 

} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc == 2) {      
        function1(argv);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error! Incorrect syntax");
    }

    return 0;
}

for exampe i gave this a file with these 4 lines:
abcdefgh
123456789
101010101
ababababa

and the program printed me out this:
«Data received through pipe: efgh
«Data received through pipe: 56789
«Data received through pipe: 10101
«Data received through pipe: ababaabcdefgh
«Data received through pipe: 56789
«Data received through pipe: 10101
«Data received through pipe: ababa

and I expected this:
«Data received through pipe: efgh
«Data received through pipe: 56789
«Data received through pipe: 10101
«Data received through pipe: ababa


With the information in the question we have to guess from your code, what you are trying to implement. As it does not give the expected output, your implementation might be wrong, so our reverse-engineered understanding might also be wrong.
I suggest to [edit] the question and explain what processes you expect to get, what they will do and how they are expected to communicate. Drawing a diagram for showing the communication might also help. Are you aware that after pid1 = fork();, both parent and child will do pid2 = fork();, so you will have 4 processes at this point?

pid1 = fork(); then pid2 = fork(); does create 3 children... The second fork() will be executed by both then parent and the child of the first fork(). This might be the source of your problem.

What's the point of using pipe and fork implementing cut ?
